# rss downloader script

Tags: linux, download, rss, wget

I have a Synology NAS that is powered by linux at my house. I'm looking to set up a cron script to check a group of rss feeds and auto download new video podcasts to a shared folder. I can do most of the scripting, such as deleting files older than 3 weeks and the wget parts. But I'm not sure how to parse the rss feed and check dates to only grab the latest. I figured its best not to re-invent the wheel and surly someone out there has a command line rss downloader or some such script.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [rsstail](http://www.vanheusden.com/rsstail/) or [tvrss](http://tvtrss.sourceforge.net)